# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of attributes in the string + Mahout

Tags: mahout

I am trying to create a file descriptor using the command:

```
$ MAHOUT_HOME/core/target/mahout-core--job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p testdata/KDDTrain+.arff -f testdata/KDDTrain+.info -d N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L
```

from the link:
https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html on my data file but whatever file I take and change the number of attributes string `N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L` .

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of attributes in the string
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but I had a more acute answer that I discovered after landing here with the same problem.

In this particular case, the problem I found was that **the format of data file** (from http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/) seems to have **changed from the example** as listed on the [Mahout Random Forest example page](https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html).

The example lists a line format with the specifier

`N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L`

but there's an extra element at the end of the lines; for example:

`13,tcp,telnet,SF,118,2425,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,26,10,0.38,0.12,0.04,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.12,0.30,guess_passwd,2`

which has one more field. Adding another number field (`N`) to the end of the specifier, as

`N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L N`

I had luck using just the plain `.txt` file format instead of the `.arff` file format.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons for which you might get an error like that...

1. **Wrong Descriptor**: Putting this for a sake of completeness. You must have already checked this one out. You have actually given a wrong descriptor for the data. Re-check the number and type of columns and then give them correctly to the descriptor.
2. **Bad separator**: Re-check the delimiter used in the data. That also might create some trouble. May be the data you have has some wrongly placed delimiter in some records. Make sure of that.
3. **Special Characters**: In my few experiments, I have noticed mahout does not enjoy if there are certain special characters, or data consists of characters of language other than English (unless of course, you tweak around the code). So make sure you have a way of handling them, and you should be good to go.

Anyways all these fight just so you can create a descriptor of the data. ATB.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was having special characters in the text file.

Comment: Kindly "upvote" and "accept" the answer, if you are happy with it (kinda new here so would love some reputation :P)